# Reference request: graded-Hom-Lie algebras

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, deformation-theory

I am looking for references regarding graded Hom-Lie algebras such as graded by $\mathbb{Z}_{i}$,including some examples. I would be grateful if you help me in this respect.